# Mockito Problems : org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:

Tags: java, mockito

```
@Test
    public void testSuccess() {
        System.out.println(Mockito.anyObject()+"");
        System.out.println(getRegistrationStatusManager.getRegistrationStatus(Mockito.anyObject()));

    }
```

I am just trying to run this where I am simply printing out the statement and a response but I get this error:-
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

Can someone explain me why in printing this I am getting such issue in 2nd line?

Comment: Please be clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Mockito matchers can only be used with mocks, they cannot be used with a sys out.